# C++, законность return внутри try или catch?

Tags: c++, исключения, return, try, catch

Скажите, пожалуйста, насколько законно осуществлять возврат из функции прямо из блоков `try/catch`?

Например:

```
bool func()
{
    try
    {
        sub_func();
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Конечно законно. В таких простых вещах я бы доверял компилятору: раз GCC и Clang c `-pedantic-errors` не ругаются, то все хорошо.

Comment: Ничего незаконного, собственно. Вот если уберёте в try или catch return - это уже будет критично)

Comment: а почему это должно быть незаконно?

Comment: @Grundy Видимо человек привык, что в C/C++ неопределенное поведение из всех щелей лезет, и теперь осторожничает. (¬‿¬)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, все верно, зашуганный я уже.